# Issue In Incoming Call in Android Using Ionic Capacitor cordova-plugin-twiliovoicesdk,

Tags: twilio-click-to-call, ionic6, incoming-call

'Incoming handler is not getting fired while I am getting Notification from FCM.'
[In The Image you can see the Piece of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Eoe.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make things run more smoothly, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of how SO works and especially [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please edit your question with more detail so others could help you out.